# Viewing file information in PHP?

Tags: php, file, uploading

I have just made a file upload form, and so far I have it so that users can only upload their own .mp3's;

Currently, all my form does is change the filename to $username . " - " . $title; in which the variables they enter;

The form is still in beta, however, and I am asking if there is a way I can view the file information (for .mp3 if not all files) with PHP, and then rewrite the file information with the $username and $title, and additional inputs from the user - that is, before uploading the file.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [getID3()](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) parser to get MP3 file information.

There are also [these ID3 PHP functions](http://php.mirrors.ilisys.com.au/manual/en/ref.id3.php) available.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're after? http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

The are various ways of doing this....there is a pecl ext called id3 which allows you to read and set tags to the mp3 file.

link to pecl:http://pecl.php.net/package/id3  , also here is a link to a nice tutorial on how to use the ext....http://devzone.zend.com/article/4025-Reading-and-Writing-MP3-and-Photo-Metadata-with-PECL-

Should the mp3 tags not be set on the file, you can always try [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.mplayerhq.hu/) which will give all the information about the file encoding ...there is also a php lib that wraps around ffmpeg which might be useful http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-phpclass/

Answer (score 1):

If you can't install the php id3 module you can use [this function](http://www.barattalo.it/2010/02/22/reading-mp3-informations-with-php-id3-tags/).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just trying to rename the file.  If that's the case you'd do something like this:

```
copy($OrigPath . $OrigFilename, $OrigPath . $Username . " - " . $Title . $OrigFilename);
```

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

G-Man

Answer (score 0):

If you're really asking if you can get file information "before uploading the file," then No, you can't. You can't read files on a client's hard drive from a web server. Other answers cover what you can do after the file is uploaded.